# Setting pandas plotting to default ax=plt.gca()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The situation is I'm running python interactively in Spyder and doing lots of plotting of pandas DataFrames. By default, if `df` is a DataFrame, then `df.plot()` creates a new window. So, if I do that a lot, I end up with a bunch of old plot windows that I need to close.

This can be avoided by using `df.plot(ax=plt.gca())`, which then tells pandas to re-use the last axes, and so it doesn't create a new window. But I don't want to write `ax=plt.gca()` every time.

I've searched but haven't found anything.  Is there any way to set this as a default?

Comment: As a last resort you could always copy the relevant pandas method to a separate file, modify it and monkey-patch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood your question correctly, this may be your answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

data = [[1, 1],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 6]]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y'])

plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'])

plt.show()
```

The previous figure is cleared by calling `plt.clf()` before plotting the new data.

Comment: This can, of course, also be done without labeling your columns.

Comment: This works, but it's even more extra typing. I want to be able to just write the clean and concise `df.plot()`